# Solve Deeply Nested View Controller Hierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

This is more of an app design question and not a code specific one.

My problem is that I have an iPhone app that uses a single UINavigationController and a user can tap on data items to push UIViewControllers with more and more detailed information.

Example:

Main Menu -> Category list -> Brand list -> Brand Details -> Product List -> Product Details -> Associated Brands list -> Brand Details -> Products List -> Product Details -> etc

When they want to get back to the main to the main menu they have to hit the back button, like, 10 times. This is obviously a horrible user experience but necessary because of the amount of screen space on the iPhone which requires a lot of supplemental views for my deeply nested data.

How did you guys solve this problem?

I heard that a "hamburger" button / side drawer is the way to go but that was a big "no no" at WWDC 2014 and it causes situations like in the Amazon app where there's both a hamburger and back button at the same time while also displaying only one or the other at various other times.

I was also thinking of possibly tapping on the Navigation bar title to unwind to the main menu but it doesn't seem intuitive to figure out and I haven't seen it used in other apps.

Any advice on how you managed to get around this app design issue would be helpful.

Edit:
**I know how to unwind and I know how to pop to root. The question is about the "app design". How do you design your app in a way so that your user doesn't have to tap the back button 10 times? I don't want to add a "Go to main menu" button on every view and Apple specifically said side-drawers/hamburger buttons were a bad idea.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many ways having deeply nested things aren't necessarily bad 'app design' by Apple's standards as long as the context continues to be the same. Say for example you have an educational app that plays videos. A fairly deep hierarchy could look like this:

View Teacher Page -> View Course By Teacher -> View First Lesson in Course -> View Pop Quiz from the lesson

In this situation the deeply nested navigation controller is an implicit breadcrumb that you see on standard webpages. Everything that is pushed onto the navigation controller stack makes sense in the context of the previous view controller.

Can you give more details about the specific use case here? It's hard to help with such a generic question. Also you might consider checking out UserExperience on StackExchange rather than StackOverflow, which is meant for coding questions specifically.

Comment: Your example is a really good example of my app, but let's say you add a few more nests to that. This means, if the user is on the bottom-most nest and want to go to the main menu, they have to tap the back button around 8 times. Is that an acceptable user experience?

Comment: I think it's totally reasonable. If you want more separation I think a UITabView can go a long ways as well. Take a long look at the App Store app, which is one of the best examples for this. You can go in really deep if you want (tapping the table rows at the bottom of app pages), but it still feels simple. Tab Views also have the nice power feature of being able to double tap on the tab icon and it unwinds back to the root. Feel free to PM me if you want additional help!

Comment: I originally ignored Tab Views because my main menu had, like, 8 things on it but I think I can totally trim that down (or group them appropriately) and get it onto tabs instead. Thanks for opening my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigate to first viewController, you can use popToRootViewControllerAnimated: or you can use popToViewController:animated: in case you want navigate to a specific viewController.

Comment: I know how to unwind and I know how to pop to root. The question is about the "app design". How do you design your app in a way so that your user doesn't have to tap the back button 10 times? I don't want to add a "Go to main menu" button on every view...

Comment: True, and really complex decision. You can subclass UINavigationBar and track the popViewController:, if user pop more than two view controllers in a second, pop to root.

Answer (score 0):

Use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` to go back to the root viewController.

```
-(IBAction)backButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to remove their ability to go back one or two levels and then tap on something different. I just want to know how most app designers present the user with the ability to go to main menu when needed.... without adding a "go to main menu" button on every single view or using a hamburger button system that Apple recommends against.

Comment: For that you can use side drawer.So that you can go to any category from there.

Comment: That's the hamburger button that Apple says we shouldn't use at WWDC last year, however, maybe you're right and this particular type of app needs to go this route.

Comment: depend on your requirement you can consider modal segue also.So you will be on the same view controller.